# ¿Como seleccionar el valor mínimo entre 2 fechas similares?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla con diferentes fechas y diferentes precios y quiero sacar el valor mínimo de esas fechas:

```
SELECT t1.nombre, min(t1.precio), t1.fecha_desde, t1.fecha_hasta
FROM tabla1 t1
WHERE t1.nombre = 'un_nombre' 
AND t1.precio != "-"
AND t1.fecha_hasta BETWEEN CURDATE() AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY t1.nombre, t1.precio, t1.fecha_desde, t1.fecha_hasta
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
nombre     |   min(t1.precio) |    fecha_desde    |   fecha_hasta
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
un_nombre           117            2017-03-30         2017-05-28
un_nombre           132            2017-03-30         2017-05-28
un_nombre            91            2017-05-31         2017-07-31
un_nombre           107            2017-05-31         2017-07-31
un_nombre            95            2017-08-01         2017-09-30
un_nombre           111            2017-08-01         2017-09-30
```

Pero necesitaría solo el valor mínimo:

```
nombre     |   min(t1.precio) |    fecha_desde    |   fecha_hasta
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
un_nombre           117            2017-03-30         2017-05-28    
un_nombre            91            2017-05-31         2017-07-31
un_nombre            95            2017-08-01         2017-09-30
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://rextester.com/OJSBFB28552)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En tu consulta original

```
SELECT t1.nombre, min(t1.precio), t1.fecha_desde, t1.fecha_hasta
FROM tabla1 t1
WHERE t1.nombre = 'un_nombre' 
AND t1.precio != "-"
AND t1.fecha_hasta BETWEEN CURDATE() AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY t1.nombre, t1.precio, t1.fecha_desde, t1.fecha_hasta
```

Estás agrupando por precio. Si precio está en la cláusula GROUP BY esa query entiendo retornará los distintos precios para cada rango (NxM), pero no el mínimo para cada rango (1xM).

La consulta debiera ser

```
SELECT t1.nombre, min(t1.precio), t1.fecha_desde, t1.fecha_hasta
FROM tabla1 t1
WHERE t1.nombre = 'un_nombre' 
AND t1.precio != "-"
AND t1.fecha_hasta BETWEEN CURDATE() AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY t1.nombre, t1.fecha_desde, t1.fecha_hasta
```

**EDIT:**

Mirando el fiddle, veo que `precio` es un string, y por tanto se ordena alfabéticamente. Una cadena que empieza con 1 es menor a una que empieza con 9, y por tanto 117 es menor que 91.

Hay que convertirlo a número de la forma:

```
SELECT t1.nombre, min(1 * t1.precio), t1.fecha_desde, t1.fecha_hasta
FROM tabla1 t1
WHERE t1.nombre = 'un_nombre' 
AND t1.precio != "-"
AND t1.fecha_hasta BETWEEN CURDATE() AND '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY t1.nombre, t1.fecha_desde, t1.fecha_hasta
```

Comment: Si [a esto te refieres](https://i.imgur.com/yjhIYq5.png) ves que la fecha `31-05-2017` tiene un precio de `107` cuando [el minimo precio es `91`](https://i.imgur.com/mL51iv5.png)

Comment: Tiene razón @lois6b

Comment: (solo porque cometí un error similar y me lo explicaste antes, @aldanux XDD)

Comment: Es porque hay que convertir el precio a número. Eran textos y estaba entregando el mínimo por orden alfabético

Comment: Perfecto mostro... gracias

Comment: ohhhh. hahahah como no me di cuenta... xD buen ojo! Mi query de antes funcionaba entonces xDD